# Add storm in PATH

Tags: linux, apache-storm

Here the steps i should do it

> 1-  Download a Storm release , unpack it, and put the unpacked bin/
> directory on your PATH
>
> 2- To be able to start and stop topologies on a remote cluster
> , put the cluster information in ~/.storm/storm.yaml

i downloaded storm release and setting up it
i want to do that
"put the unpacked bin/ directory on your PATH"

cause i can't use storm as a command

and the second step what's the cluster info should i do in storm.yaml ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us say your storm is unpacked at `/home/your/download/storm`

1. define that as an env variable by

   ```
   STORM_HOME="/home/your/download/storm"
   ```
2. export this variable by

   ```
   export STORM_HOME
   ```
3. do not forget to import the path

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:$STORM_HOME/bin
   ```

then you can use storm command in it.

Comment: yes just append those command at the end of `.bashrc` file, then `source .bashrc` and those env variable will available

Comment: any output after you executed?

Comment: are you sure `$STORM_HOME/bin` are included in `$PATH` env var? please check it with `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Making it more simple with a single export command.

I downloaded `apache storm` from [`here`](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/storm/apache-storm-1.0.5/apache-storm-1.0.5.tar.gz) and Lets say My download path is `/home/username/Downloads/apache-storm-1.0.5`

Change your actual path in this command and hit this at terminal.

> export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/Downloads/apache-storm-1.0.5/bin

all done.